# How to create a form validation with tab using yup and useForm on react?

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I created this form component in react with validation using yup and react hook form. I also created a tab like structure inside the form to avoid the vertical scroll. There's two option on how can a user change the tab by pressing the next button or dotted navigation below. The issue is I can't think a solution on how can I validate those input field after the user decided to click the dotted navigation or the next button without typing on the input field. All the validation is being done after the user click the submit button. The output that I want is if the user decided to click the next or dotted navigation without providing a data the form will trigger the validation without pressing the onsubmit.

Thanks!

```
const schema = yup.object().shape({
  projectName: yup.string().required('Please enter project name here'),
  projectClient: yup
    .string()
    .required('Please choose your client for this project'),
});

const createProject = () => {
const [projectInfo, setProjectInfo] = useState({
    projectName: '',
    projectClientName: '',
  });

const { register, errors, handleSubmit } = useForm({
    resolver: yupResolver(schema),
    mode: 'all',
  });
}

const handleOnSubmit = () => {
    dispatch(registerProject(projectInfo));
 };

return (

<form
              className='form-container w-full flex flex-col relative'
              onSubmit={handleSubmit(handleOnSubmit)}
            >
              
              <div
                className={`w-full ${
                  tabActive === 'Create' ? 'block' : 'hidden'
                }`}
              >
                <div className='relative rounded-tl-lg rounded-tr-lg'>
                  <h4 className='text-grey text-lg font-bold text-center tracking-wider'>
                    Create Project
                  </h4>
                  <XIcon
                    className='w-5 h-5 absolute top-0 right-0 opacity-40 cursor-pointer'
                    aria-hidden='true'
                    onClick={() => showProjectCreate(false)}
                  />
                </div>
                <div className='pt-10'>
                  <label className='text-sm font-medium' htmlFor='password'>
                    Project name
                  </label>
                  <div className='mt-2 relative'>
                    <InputElement
                      className={`w-full px-4 py-5 text-sm leading-tight rounded-md appearance-none ${
                        errors.projectName
                          ? 'border-danger focus:border-danger'
                          : 'border focus:border-primary'
                      } border focus:border-primary focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline`}
                      id='projectName'
                      name='projectName'
                      type='text'
                      placeholder='Enter your project name here'
                      ref={register}
                      value={projectInfo.projectName}
                      onChange={handleOnChange}
                    />
                    <p className='text-xxs text-danger mt-2 absolute'>
                      {errors.projectName?.message}
                    </p>
                  </div>
                </div>
<div className='pt-10'>
                  <label className='text-sm font-medium' htmlFor='projectClientName'>
                    Project client name
                  </label>
                  <div className='mt-2 relative'>
                    <InputElement
                      className={`w-full px-4 py-5 text-sm leading-tight rounded-md appearance-none ${
                        errors.projectName
                          ? 'border-danger focus:border-danger'
                          : 'border focus:border-primary'
                      } border focus:border-primary focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline`}
                      id='projectClientName'
                      name='projectClientName'
                      type='text'
                      placeholder='Enter your project name here'
                      ref={register}
                      value={projectInfo.projectClientName}
                      onChange={handleOnChange}
                    />
                    <p className='text-xxs text-danger mt-2 absolute'>
                      {errors.projectName?.message}
                    </p>
                  </div>
                </div>
</div>
</form>

)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do the validation Onblur event ?

Comment: https://codepen.io/ngminhtrung/pen/odXXzo